# runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'. Why does one piece works but the other doesn't?

Tags: pointers, linked-list

I was trying to solve this question on leetcode of finding the middle point of a linked list.

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* middleNode(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* slow=head,* fast=head;
        while(fast->next!=NULL && fast!=NULL)
            slow=slow->next,
            fast=fast->next->next;
        return slow;
    }
};
```

The above code gives error.

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* middleNode(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* slow=head,* fast=head;
        while(fast!=NULL && fast->next!=NULL)
            slow=slow->next,
            fast=fast->next->next;
        return slow;
    }
};
```

While this one works.
Why is that? Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using && it doesn't calculate fully, if the first statement is `false` then second statement wouldn't calculate at all. So in the first case you don't check if `fast` is NULL, but trying to use operation -> on NULL, which is `access within null pointer`.

But in the second code it's always guaranteed that `fast != NULL` by the time you are using operation -> (fast->next).